# Combine Google Maps API & Google Maps Data API

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps

When i embed a map from my maps i use the link that googgle maps provides me
This map i can manipulate with **Google Maps Data API and Java**

`<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&amp;hl=el&amp;geocode=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;msa=0&amp;
msid=118122212106261754884.00047ec38974a377d47dd&amp;
ll=39.527348,21.00174&amp;spn=0,0&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />`

but then i can't put it on a div and manipulate it with **Google Maps API and Javascript**
to catch events for example

Now if i use
[The "Hello, World" of Google Maps](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html) i can do all of the above but this map is not in "My Maps" so i can't use the gui and all the operations the google maps give me for a kind of "administration" on the map

How can i combine these technologies?
Can Mapplets help me?
 [Click here for an example i made](http://www.infofire.gr/testGis/myTest.html)
In this example i cannot manipulate the second map with javascript i.e. setCenter() on the map

I'am confused :(

Answer (score 1):

Embedding a Google Map is different from using the Google Maps API. You have a couple of options here - you can update your MyMap, export is as KML (via the View in Google Earth link) and load it using GGeoXML.

Alternatively, you can use the Maps Data API to load data from your My Map and programmatically add it to the map. Here is a sample: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/college-finder/index.html.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried following the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/) for the Google Maps API? It seems like you aren't making a proper request to the the Google Maps service.

If you have some kind of "administration" marking on the maps, that would indicate to me that perhaps you are using the test code - and probably need to sign up for an API key in order to remove this marking.

Comment: Please check here:
http://www.infofire.gr/testGis/myTest.html
I use google maps api for the first map and 
google maps<b>Data</b> api in the second.
My problem is that i can't manipulate the second map with javascript 
i.e i can't execute setCenter() on this map