# Can I emded a public GMap and then programmatically modify it?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to embed a public gmap:

```
        <iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=207932289133051333830.000457f61fc6dcab1aff1&amp;ll=46.495556,11.359863&amp;spn=0.017726,0.025749&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

I also know how to create one using JavaScript and program as I wish.

What I'm trying to do is combine the two approaches:
I embed the public gmap, but then programmatically modify it (or (better) add an overlay on top of it). Is this possible? Any examples?

Comment: What do you mean by "modify" exactly?

Comment: Related: http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199421/combine-google-maps-api-google-maps-data-api

Comment: @Pekka: I want to add/change markers with a special icon

Comment: @simpatico check out the examples linked, they should help.

Comment: @Pekka: any particular example? It seems that Google doesn't support it anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible anymore:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/forum.html

Answer (score 1):

Give it an ID, then you can find it and change it.

```
<iframe id="MyFrame" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=207932289133051333830.000457f61fc6dcab1aff1&amp;ll=46.495556,11.359863&amp;spn=0.017726,0.025749&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Then use:

```
document.getElementById("MyFrame")
```

Then you can change the element's attributes with set `setAttribute()`

More about this: [Change HTML class attribute using javascript](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/01/change-class-attribute-using-javascript.html)

Comment: but how do i create an overlay setting attributes that way? Essentially I need to change some specific markers icons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Google Maps API to add markers.

Check out the [custom marker example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html) in the [Google Maps V3 API demo gallery](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html). The code is too long to copy + paste here, but it should answer your basic question.

For more basic things, look at the M[aps API code samples.](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html)

Comment: no, this is not it. http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html

Comment: @simpatico can you describe in more detail what you want then?